smoothly transition css variable color in animation?
Is there a way to animate css variable colors such that there is smooth interpolation between keyframe values?
E.g. below has hard transitions:


:root {
  --global-color: #ff0000;
  animation: colorChange 2s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes colorChange {
  0% { --global-color: #ff0000; }
  50% { --global-color: #800080; }
  100% { --global-color: #0000ff; }
}

.element {
  background-color: var(--global-color);
}
<div class="element">
hello
</div>



I could of course just animate on background-color and it will work in this local example. However there are cases where you may want animation shared between multiple components with a variable. So I am wondering if it's possible to do this with a root css variable.
Thanks!
